# SQL Server 2012/2014 Calculate running count

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowcount

I am trying to create a query that will return a running count by date, grouped by module.

Fields in my table that I'm interested are DateID, Module. The fact that a row exists for a Module and DateID, indicates a count of 1. A module can appear multiple times for a singe DateID and there are obviously multiple modules per day as well. Running the following query almost returns what I want:

```
SELECT 
    DateID,
    Module,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Module ORDER BY DateID) [RunningCount]
FROM dbo.vwFiles
WHERE DateID IN (5467,5468)
AND Module IN ('PC','DD','NL')
ORDER BY DateID

    DateID  Module  RunningCount
    5467    DD      1
    5467    DD      2
    5467    DD      3
    5467    NL      1
    5467    NL      2
    5467    NL      3
    5467    NL      4
    5467    PC      1
    5467    PC      2
    5467    PC      3
    5468    NL      5
```

However I don't just get a single count for each DateID, I get a count for every module record on each DateID.

Modifying the query as follows:

```
SELECT DateID, Module,MAX(RunningCount) RunningCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT DateID, Module
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Module ORDER BY DateID) RunningCount
    FROM vwFiles
    WHERE DateID IN (5467,5468)
    AND Module IN ('PC','DD','NL')  
) z
GROUP BY Module, DateID
ORDER BY DateID, Module

    DateID  Module  RunningCount
    5467    DD      3
    5467    NL      4
    5467    PC      3
    5468    NL      5
```

Does give me what I want. However I would have thought that there was a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Simpler? I guess you didn't calculate running total in MS SQL 2000 :)

Comment: Can u provide with test data?

Comment: as far as i can see you are just counting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running totals are such a natural thing it's almost surprising there isn't some native way to do this. Here's a different approach, I think it's a little simpler but I also think 'simple' can be a very subjective term :)

```
declare @t table (DateId int, Module char(2))

insert @t values (5467, 'DD'),
                 (5467, 'DD'),
                 (5467, 'DD'),
                 (5467, 'NL'),
                 (5467, 'NL'),
                 (5467, 'NL'),
                 (5467, 'NL'),
                 (5467, 'PC'),
                 (5467, 'PC'),
                 (5467, 'PC'),
                 (5468, 'NL')

; with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by DateId, Module) as rn,
        t.*
    from 
        @t t
)
SELECT
    t1.DateId,
    t1.Module,
    count(distinct t2.rn)
FROM
    cte AS t1
        LEFT JOIN cte AS t2 ON t2.Module = t1.Module and t2.rn <= t1.rn
GROUP BY 
    t1.DateId, 
    t1.Module
ORDER BY 
    t1.DateId,
    t1.Module
```

There's a rather good article by Aaron Bertrand on SQLPerformance.com [Best approaches for running totals](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) - worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not a "running total" at all. You're simply counting by groups. So, you can do simply that operation:

```
SELECT DateId, Module, COUNT(*) FROM vwFiles
GROUP BY DateId,Module
```

The problem is not that you are facing a complex problem, but you're facing it in the wrong way.

Comment: Not quite right JotaBe. You solution would not provide a 'running' count as required. Yours produces the count per day, which is obviously much easier to get.

Comment: Well,I don't understand why the question title says "running total" and then, in the end of the question you show the total by Date and Module, and this overwhelming sentence: "Does give me what I want". What am I missing? Why a query that returns exactly what you expect is not a solution for your problem? I suppose there must be a reason for you to say so, please, explain.

Comment: The question title says running count. Not "running total". Running total would imply a sum which as I state, there are plenty of examples and discussions on. I do accept that my 2nd SQL statement does give me what I want but I personally think it is a little un-elegant and would have thought there would have been a native way to do it, which is why I asked.

Comment: Well, I don't mind if it's running total or running count. The missing part in your question or in your solution is the "running" part. Running implies that your query returns a set of rows with a result for each row which includes some kind of aggregate or count including the rows up to that specific row. Your result doesn't have a running total at all. You don't have to worry how SQL Server calculates it. It only matters to get the result you need. What is the point in forcing SQL Server to calculate a running total to keep only the grand total? That's pointless. Am I still missing anything?